# Facing error while installing DAISYUI . in react

Tags: css, reactjs, daisyui

I have successfully installed tailwind css. in my react project. but when i write
`npm i daisyui` then error start coming. i dont know why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need Tailwind CSS 3.0 and Autoprefixer 10.0 but currently you have Autoprefixer 9.8.8 installed

Answer (score 0):

Update your node version. Install a new version of Node.

Via npm:

#### n lts

#### n latest

Answer (score 0):

Like the person mentioned the postcss and autoprefixer are outdated to deal with this what i did was

1. npm install -g npm ( to update my npm to latest)
2. npm install autoprefixer@latest
3. npm install postcss@latest
4. npm install daisyui